# calling opencv HoughCircles from python. error: (-5) Unrecognized method id

Tags: python, opencv

Playing with python and opencv, installed with pytonxy

I'm trying to call HoughCircles but getting the following error:

```
OpenCV Error: Bad argument (Unrecognized method id) in unknown function, file ..\..\..\OpenCV-2.4.2\modules\imgproc\src\hough.cpp, line 1069
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
cv2.error: ..\..\..\OpenCV-2.4.2\modules\imgproc\src\hough.cpp:1069: error: (-5) Unrecognized method id
```

The code is real simple:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
vidCap =cv2.VideoCapture("D:\movies\VID_20130614_143125.mp4")
b, im = vidCap.read()

gray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, 1, cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 100)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html#houghcircles) it looks as if `dp` and `method` are positional arguments and you have them in the wrong order.

So instead of:

```
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, 1, cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 100)
```

It should be:

```
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 100)
```

Comment: @user2232888 If that fixed your problem you should accept it as the answer for future people that come across the same problem.

Comment: I thought I did. I clicked the green v next to the answer. Is there another way of doing it?